# Sequence diverging to infinitive.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove that the sequence diverges to negative infinitive.

$ x_n = n - 3n^2$ as $n$ grows.

Proof: By definition, a sequence approaches negative infinitive iff for every real number $M$, there exists a natural $N$ such that $n \ge N \to x_n \lt M$.

Now, $x_n = n - 3n^2 = n(1 - 3n) \lt 3n$. 
So $n \ge N$ implies $n - 3n^2 = n(1 - 3n) \lt 3n \lt 3N \lt M$

I am having trouble understanding how to find big $M$. Thank you.

Comment: Why "choose" $M$? Shouldn't you start by assuming that $x_n < M$ and *then* expressing $N$ *in terms of* $M$, thus proving $N$'s existence (as per the definition)?

Comment: An infinitive is an English grammatical term. I think you mean infinity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hint:***

$$ x_n = n - 3n^2 = (n - n^2) -2n^2  $$

You can use induction to prove that $ n - n^2 \le 0  $ whence it follows that $$x_n \le  -2n^2 \le -2n $$

Comment: So after proving (n-n^2) by induction, I can conclude x_n <= -2n^2 <= -2n <= -2N < M ?

Comment: No. You can conclude that $ x_n \le -2n $ for every natural number $n$. Let $M$  be an arbitrary real number. Then by the unboundedness of the set $\Bbb N$, there is $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $ N \gt -M $. Then $$ n\ge N \implies x_n \le -2n \le -2N \le -N \lt M $$